# Query MongoDB with length criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have several documents in a MongoDB Collection, with a field 'name' (which is a String).

How can I perform queries like `7 <= name.length  <= 14`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a [JavaScript expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D).

```
User.where("this.name.length >= 7 && this.name.length <= 14")
```

Comment: This query is ineffienct and won't uses indexes!

Comment: I know, but it didn't request for the most efficient way. The most way would be to add a `name_lenght` attribute, calculate it every time the `name` is saved, add an index on the field and query for the field.

Answer (score 13):

Mongo provides a few ways to perform a query with length criteria – `$where` or `$regex` are two great options however I would recommend using `$regex` due to better query performance.

---

## [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) *(slower)*

#### Accepts either a JavaScript expression or function in queries

Example:

```
db.collection.find({ $where: 'this.name.length >= 7 && this.name.length <= 14' })
```

*Note: The `$where` operator **will not** take advantage of your database indexes, resulting in a much slower query. - [Source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)*

---

## [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) *(faster)*

#### Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries

Example:

```
db.collection.find({ name: { $regex: /^.{7,14}$/ } })
```

*Note: The `$regex` operator **will** take advantage of your database indexes, resulting in a much faster query (if your collection is indexed properly). - [Source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)*

Comment: @muistooshort, (1) incorrect…indexes will still be used even if you do not start your pattern with `^` (see Mongo's note about [Index Use](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)). It states that _further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix expression"_ (e.g. pattern starts with `^`). (2) I have not benchmarked both operators, but per [Mongo's documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use), it states that `$regex` using indexes _can be faster than a collection scan_.

Answer (score 4):

You can use MongoDB's $where query parameter to submit javascript to the server.  E.g.,:

```
db.myCollection.find( {$where: "(7 <= this.name.length) && (this.name.length <= 14)"} )
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D

Comment: I guess you meant `this.name.length` like Simone posted above?

Answer (score 0):

`$where` queries are not very efficient. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D)

If this is a frequently executed query, you might want to store the length in a separate field. [Denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)